# OneToMany mapping in hibernate. Value is coming null

Tags: java, hibernate-mapping

I have a student class and I have an Account class which have @OneToMany relationship. One Student to many accounts.My both the tables has been created. My account table has a field Student_id in it, but value is coming as null. Could you please help where I am doing wrong.

```
    import java.util.Collection;
    import java.util.Set;

    import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
    import javax.persistence.Column;
    import javax.persistence.Entity;
    import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
    import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
    import javax.persistence.Id;
    import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
    import javax.persistence.JoinTable;
    import javax.persistence.ManyToMany;
    import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
    import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
    import javax.persistence.Table;

    @Entity
    @Table(name = "Student_Information")
    public class Student {

        @Id
        private int id;

        @Column
        private String name;


        @OneToOne(targetEntity=Address.class , cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
        @JoinColumn(name="addressId" , referencedColumnName = "addressId")
        private Address adId;

        @OneToMany(mappedBy="student",cascade= CascadeType.ALL)
        private Collection<Account> account;


        @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
        @JoinTable(name = "STUDENT_CERTIFICATION", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "id") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "certId") })
        private Collection<Certification> certId;


        public Collection<Account> getAccount() {
            return account;
        }

        public void setAccount(Collection<Account> account) {
            this.account = account;
        }

        public Collection<Certification> getCertId() {
            return certId;
        }

        public void setCertId(Collection<Certification> certId) {
            this.certId = certId;
        }


        public int getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(int id) {
            this.id = id;
        }
        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }
        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }
        public Address getAdId() {
            return adId;
        }

        public void setAdId(Address adId) {
            this.adId = adId;
        }

    }

Account Class




import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "Account")
public class Account {

    @Id
    private int accountId;


    @Column
    private String accountNumber;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="id")
    private Student id;

    public Student getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Student id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getAccountId() {
        return accountId;
    }

    public void setAccountId(int accountId) {
        this.accountId = accountId;
    }

    public String getAccountNumber() {
        return accountNumber;
    }

    public void setAccountNumber(String accountNumber) {
        this.accountNumber = accountNumber;
    }


}
```

I have a student class and I have an Account class which have @OneToMany relationship. One Student to many accounts.My both the tables has been created. My account table has a field Student_id in it, but value is coming as null. Could you please help where I am doing wrong.

Comment: Try change the field name from id to student in the class Account

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is because the name in join column annotation, this name should match with the actual name of the column in your table, in this case as you have said student_id

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="student_id")
private Student id;
```

Comment: Tried the same but getting null value.

Answer (score 0):

`@OneToMany(mappedBy="student")` is not correct.

Should be `@OneToMany(mappedBy="id")`

Comment: Tried but same thing I am getting again null

Answer (score 0):

try this, put this code below in Student class:

```
    @OneToMany(cascade= CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="student",)
    private Collection<Account> account;
```

and put this line below in Account:

```
    @ManyToOne()
    @JoinColumn(name = "account_id", columnDefinition = "BigInt")
    private Student student;
```

good luck...

Comment: private Student id; in this case, ID is not a good name, and because of that, I changed that to student...

Answer (score 0):

The student's `id` inside `Account` entity is not necessary, you should only have an `id` for one account like:

```
// Account class:

@Id
private int account_id; //should not be named 'id'
```

And then join it with a `@OneToMany` annotation in the `Student` entity:

```
// Student class:

@Id
private int id;

@JoinColumn(name="id") // student's id
@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
private Collection<Account> accounts;
```